# Whe importing dataframe and header option is false xlwings still imports header

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, xlwings

I am attempting to import data from a pandas dataframe. For ease of manipulation on the end user side I am importing the data into a pre-defined table 'Table1'. This table already contains headers, so I am trying not to import them from the dataframe.

```
'''Paste Dataframe into Excel'''
wb.sheets['Data'].clear_contents
wb.sheets['Data'].range('Table1').value = df
wb.sheets['Data'].range('Table1').options(pd.DataFrame, index=False, header=False).expand().value
```

This currently results in 2 rows of headers in my excel table. Am I missing documentation on a better way to export this data in a proper Excel table? Am I misunderstanding the function of the header option?

Comment: Have a look at the docs here: https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/converters.html#pandas-dataframe-converter You'll need to set the options in your 2nd code line, when you write the dataframe

Answer (score 1):

Pandas has a method to export dataframe as excel table with a lot of params.

```
your_dataframe.to_excel('document.xlsx')
```

Check out the documentation for more details : 
[pandas.DataFrame.to_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html)

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same problem yesterday, the `.options` method should be applied when inserting the value. Doing it this way worked fine for me:

```
wb.sheets['Data'].clear_contents
wb.sheets['Data'].range('Table1').options(index=False, header=False).value  = df
wb.sheets['Data'].range('Table1').options(pd.DataFrame).expand().value
```

Also it is how it is shown in xlwings documentation.
https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/datastructures.html